# Relacionamentos MySQL: Problema na consulta

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp-2

Tenho o seguinte cenário

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Preciso buscar todas as `consulta_tipos` com `consulta_itens` alinhados e marcar as que estão em `cliente_consulta_tipo` e `cliente_consulta_itens`, além disso preciso buscar os `fornecedores` de `consulta_itens` e marcar os respectivos de acordo com as `cliente_consulta_itens`.

Em termos práticos: `ConsultaTipo`: A tem `ConsultaItem`: 1 e 2. O cliente tem disponível somente o `ConsultaItem`: 2, que tem os `Fornecedores` X e Y.

Já tentei de todas as formas realizar esta busca, mas não tive sucesso. Em tempo: estou programando em PHP (CakePHP).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dê uma olhada na documentação do CakePHP referente à [associações entre Models](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/associations-linking-models-together.html) (coloquei a versão 2.x pois acredito que seja o seu caso) e veja os exemplos de usos de associações de Models, assim como a utilização do atributo *[Recursive](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/model-attributes.html#recursive)* para poder trazer todos itens de tabelas que estejam associadas.

Exemplo

Modelo:

[image: model]

Exemplo relacionamento n-n

*Model* Tabela1:

```
<?php
App::uses('AppModel', 'Model');
class Tabela1 extends AppModel {
    public $useTable = 'tabela_1';
    public $hasAndBelongsToMany = array(
      'Tabela2' =>
        array(
          'className' => 'Tabela2',
          'joinTable' => 'tabela_relacionamento_1_2',
          'foreignKey' => 'tabela_1_id',
          'associationForeignKey' => 'tabela_2_id'
        ),
    );

    public function getAll(){
      //Essa função irá retornar todos os itens da tabela_1 e também
      //retornar os os itens que estão associados a cada um dos itens.
      //Ex: $allItens = array(0 => array(
      //  'Tabela1' => array('id' => 1, 'att1' => 'atributo1', att2 => 'atributo2'),
      //  'Tabela2 => array('id' => 1, 'attr1' => 'attributo1', 'attr2' => 'attributo2)
      //));
      $allItens = $this->find('all',
        'recursive' => 2
      );
      return $allItens;
    }
}
```

*Model* Tabela2:

```
<?php
App::uses('AppModel', 'Model');
class Tabela2 extends AppModel {
    public $useTable = 'tabela_2';
    public $hasAndBelongsToMany = array(
      'Tabela1' =>
        array(
          'className' => 'Tabela1',
          'joinTable' => 'tabela_relacionamento_1_2',
          'foreignKey' => 'tabela_2_id',
          'associationForeignKey' => 'tabela_1_id'
        ),
    );
}
```

Relacionamento 1-n

*Model* Tabela3:

```
<?php
App::uses('AppModel', 'Model');
class Tabela3 extends AppModel {
    public $useTable = 'tabela_3';
    public $hasMany = array(
        'Tabela4' => array(
            'className'    => 'Tabela4',
            'foreignKey'   => 'tabela_3_id'
        )
      );
}
```

*Model* Tabela4:

```
<?php
App::uses('AppModel', 'Model');
class Tabela2 extends AppModel {
    public $useTable = 'tabela_4';
    public $belongsTo = array(
        'Tabela3' => array(
            'className'    => 'Tabela3',
            'foreignKey'   => 'tabela_3_id'
        )
    );

    public function getAll(){
      //Essa função irá retornar todos os itens da *tabela_3* e também
      //retornar os os itens que estão associados a cada um dos itens.
      //Ex: $allItens = array(0 => array(
      //  'Tabela4' => array('id' => 1, 'attribute1' => 'att1', attribute2 => 'att2'),
      //  'Tabela3 => array('id' => 1, 'atributo1' => 'at1', 'atributo2' => 'at2)
      //));
      $allItens = $this->find('all',
        'recursive' => 2
      );
      return $allItens;
    }
}
```

Comment: Você já havia postado uma resposta. É interessante juntar ambas em uma só, neste caso, juntar a anterior com esta e apaga-la após.

Comment: Conseguiu resolver seu problema @DiegoFelipe?

Comment: Juliano, não fui eu quem fiz a pergunta. O OP É o @DaniloMiguel

Comment: Verdade, confundi pelo fato do primeiro nome ser parecido